# Spoon Inria. Not resolving CtExecutableReference type and declared type depending on environment (Docker and local Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, inria-spoon

Good day.

I encountered very strange issue using Spoon analysis library in my Java project.
I get different parsing results when running same code, that uses Spoon Launcher in different environments

- 1 Environment - Spring Boot Project that is run locally from Intellij IDEA
- 2 Environment - Same Spring Boot project that is run in a Docker Container

In locally run Spring Boot project - it's all OK, but when I run the same code in Docker - I get `null` values in `CtExecutableReference.getType()` and `CtExecutableReference.getDeclaredType()`

I opened issue on GitHub - https://github.com/INRIA/spoon/issues/3926

**Here are the details**

My Spoon version is 8.2.0. (from maven repo)

I am trying to parse (build AST) of code from [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/vipinjo/assignment-consumer)
And I have troubles parsing [this class](https://github.com/vipinjo/assignment-consumer/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vipinjoseph/assignmentconsumer/service/ValueServices.java)
There are following lines here

```java
...
@Service
public class ValueServices {
    
    private ValuesRepository valuesRepository;
    
    private Queue<Values> queue;

    @Autowired
    public ValueServices(ValuesRepository valuesRepository) {
        super();
        this.valuesRepository = valuesRepository;
        this.queue = new LinkedList<Values>();
    }
    
    public List<Values> getAllValues() {
        List<Values> values = new ArrayList<>();
        this.valuesRepository.findAll().forEach(values::add);
        return values;
    }

...
}
```

When I run analysis and try to parse `CtExecutableReference` for `findAll()` method of `this.valuesRepository.findAll().forEach(values::add)` statement I get `null` values for `getType()` and `getDeclaredType()` when running my project in Docker.
When running locally both `getType()` and `getDeclaredType()`  have non-null values

The same issue happens when parsing other similar code blocks in other projects.
For example [here](https://github.com/vipinjo/betting-app/blob/master/src/main/java/com/betting/service/BetService.java)

```java
@Service
public class BetService {

    public static final String DATE_FORMAT_NOW = "yyyy-MM-dd HH";
    public static final String DATE_FORMAT_NOW_WITH_HOUR_MIN = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

    private BetRepository betRepository;

    @Autowired
    public BetService(BetRepository betRepository) {
        super();
        this.betRepository = betRepository;
    }

    public List<Bet> getAllBets() {
        List<Bet> bets = new ArrayList<Bet>();
        this.betRepository.findAll().forEach(bets::add);

        return bets;
    }
}
```

Statement with `this.betRepository.findAll()` has null in both `getType` and `getDeclaredType` when running in Docker, but ok in local environment.

At the same time [following code](https://github.com/vipinjo/betting-app/blob/master/src/test/java/com/betting/repository/BetRepositoryTest.java) is parsed well in both environments

```java
public class BetRepositoryTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;
 
    @Autowired
    private BetRepository betRepository;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Bet bet = new Bet("2018-07-06 12:56", "WIN", 103333, 1082, 500.5);
        entityManager.persist(bet);
        entityManager.flush();
       
        List<Bet> bets = betRepository.findByCustomerId(bet.getCustomerId());       
        assertThat(bet.getCustomerId() == bets.get(0).getCustomerId());
    }
}
```

and statement `betRepository.findByCustomerId()` is parsed ok and has necessary type info both in Docker and n local Spring Boot run.

I double checked local tests - and all is ok - when running code in tests from IDE or starting Spring Boot project from IDE and initialising analysis by calling service from Web UI - it OK and works as expected.

But when I build Docker image - I get null in both type and declaredType.

I'm running Spoon analysis with the following code

```java
private SourceCodeMetamodel buildMetamodelForFiles(Collection<File> javaFiles) {
        Launcher spoonAPI = new Launcher();
        log.debug("Spoon environment - {}",ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(spoonAPI.getEnvironment()));
        log.debug("Spoon model builder - {}",ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(spoonAPI.getModelBuilder()));
        Set<String> inputResources = new HashSet<>();
        for (File javaFile: javaFiles) {
            String javaDir = JavaFileUtils.getJavaFileStorageRootPath(javaFile);
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(javaDir) && !inputResources.contains(javaDir)) {
                spoonAPI.addInputResource(javaDir);
                inputResources.add(javaDir);
            }
            else if (StringUtils.isBlank(javaDir)) {
                spoonAPI.addInputResource(javaFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
        spoonAPI.buildModel();
        CtModel ctModel = spoonAPI.getModel();
        Collection<CtType<?>> modelTypes = ctModel.getAllTypes();
        return new SpoonSourceCodeMetamodel(modelTypes,false);
    }
```

Before running Launcher I tried to print it's settings. Here is what i got

```
2021-05-14 13:26:12.329 DEBUG 1 --- [         task-1] c.s.s.r.i.s.SpoonJavaSourceCodeAnalyzer  : Spoon environment - spoon.support.StandardEnvironment@4626a7ce[errorCount=0,processingStopped=false,prettyPrintingMode=FULLYQUALIFIED,warningCount=0,sourceClasspath=<null>,preserveLineNumbers=false,copyResources=true,enableComments=true,level=ERROR,shouldCompile=false,skipSelfChecks=false,complianceLevel=8,previewFeaturesEnabled=false,outputType=classes,noclasspath=true,compressionType=GZIP,sniperMode=false,ignoreDuplicateDeclarations=false,prettyPrinterCreator=<null>,useTabulations=false,tabulationSize=4,binaryOutputDirectory=/spooned-classes]

2021-05-14 13:26:12.333 DEBUG 1 --- [         task-1] c.s.s.r.i.s.SpoonJavaSourceCodeAnalyzer  : Spoon model builder - spoon.support.compiler.jdt.JDTBasedSpoonCompiler@2df98092[environment=<null>,probs=[],requestor=spoon.support.compiler.jdt.TreeBuilderRequestor@57050733,factory=spoon.reflect.factory.FactoryImpl@237d7ffa,javaCompliance=7,sources=<virtual folder>: spoon.support.compiler.VirtualFolder@42618617,templates=<virtual folder>: spoon.support.compiler.VirtualFolder@7fb32ea2,templateClasspath={},compilationUnitFilters=[],sortList=true]
```

I'm running project on Java8 - in both environments (details following).
To build docker I use following commands

```sh
FROM java:8
COPY maven /maven/
ENTRYPOINT java -Xverify:none -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:+UseSerialGC -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40 -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dspring.profiles.active=${PROFILE:-docker-dev} -jar /maven/skillcounters-sca-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I tried to switch to different Docker base images (openjdk \ alpine etc.), but nothing helped.
I tried to exclude all java run options listed above (i.e. like -XXblabla) - didn't helped either.

To get ideas about what may go wrong i print all environment (including java) data on application start.

Here what is printed for **local** environment

```sh
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render : /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.xCrhs0tTMM/Render
COMMAND_MODE : unix2003
HOME : /Users/sk
JAVA_MAIN_CLASS_66239 : org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher
JAVA_MAIN_CLASS_66249 : com.skillcounters.sca.SCAServiceApplication
LANG : ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE : ru_RU.UTF-8
LOGNAME : sk
PATH : /Users/sk/Develop/d20/db/liquibase:/Users/sk/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
PID : 66249
PWD : /Users/sk/Develop/d20/d20-git-repo/skillcounters-sca-service/skillcounters-sca-service-impl
SECURITYSESSIONID : 186a9
SHELL : /bin/bash
SSH_AUTH_SOCK : /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.ItaWSltKcA/Listeners
TMPDIR : /var/folders/lz/gjd4j2t12_39qs0hpdjqd3sh0000gn/T/
USER : sk
XPC_FLAGS : 0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME : com.apple.xpc.launchd.oneshot.0x10000002.idea
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING : 0x1F5:0x0:0x0
awt.toolkit : sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit
file.encoding : UTF-8
file.encoding.pkg : sun.io
file.separator : /
ftp.nonProxyHosts : local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16
gopherProxySet : false
http.nonProxyHosts : local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16
java.awt.graphicsenv : sun.awt.CGraphicsEnvironment
java.awt.headless : true
java.awt.printerjob : sun.lwawt.macosx.CPrinterJob
java.class.path : {all dependent jars go here - excluded them not to pollute issue...}
java.class.version : 52.0
java.endorsed.dirs : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/endorsed
java.ext.dirs : /Users/sk/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
java.home : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
java.io.tmpdir : /var/folders/lz/gjd4j2t12_39qs0hpdjqd3sh0000gn/T/
java.library.path : /Users/sk/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
java.runtime.name : Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
java.runtime.version : 1.8.0_131-b11
java.specification.name : Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.vendor : Oracle Corporation
java.specification.version : 1.8
java.vendor : Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url : http://java.oracle.com/
java.vendor.url.bug : http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
java.version : 1.8.0_131
java.vm.info : mixed mode
java.vm.name : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
java.vm.specification.name : Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.vm.specification.vendor : Oracle Corporation
java.vm.specification.version : 1.8
java.vm.vendor : Oracle Corporation
java.vm.version : 25.131-b11
```

And here is what printed in **Docker** environment

```
CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION : 20140324
HOME : /root
HOSTNAME : e297584466e8
JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION : 8u111-b14-2~bpo8+1
JAVA_HOME : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
JAVA_VERSION : 8u111
LANG : C.UTF-8
PATH : /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PID : 8
PROFILE : prod
PWD : /
awt.toolkit : sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
file.encoding : UTF-8
file.encoding.pkg : sun.io
file.separator : /
java.awt.graphicsenv : sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
java.awt.headless : true
java.awt.printerjob : sun.print.PSPrinterJob
java.class.path : /maven/skillcounters-skill-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
java.class.version : 52.0
java.endorsed.dirs : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/endorsed
java.ext.dirs : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext
java.home : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
java.io.tmpdir : /tmp
java.library.path : /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
java.protocol.handler.pkgs : org.springframework.boot.loader
java.runtime.name : OpenJDK Runtime Environment
java.runtime.version : 1.8.0_111-8u111-b14-2~bpo8+1-b14
java.security.egd : file:/dev/./urandom
java.specification.name : Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.vendor : Oracle Corporation
java.specification.version : 1.8
java.vendor : Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url : http://java.oracle.com/
java.vendor.url.bug : http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
java.version : 1.8.0_111
java.vm.info : mixed mode
java.vm.name : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
java.vm.specification.name : Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.vm.specification.vendor : Oracle Corporation
java.vm.specification.version : 1.8
java.vm.vendor : Oracle Corporation
java.vm.version : 25.111-b14
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I found some clue when I enabled Spoon Launcher logging by setting it to 'ALL'

Here is what I got in Docker environment

```sh
...
The method findAll() is undefined for the type ValuesRepository at /opt/skillcounters/filestorage/github/vipinjo/assignment-consumer/work-tree/d4e050cf3566981ba386e336c5889f8d107abfbb/src/main/java/com/vipinjoseph/assignmentconsumer/service/ValueServices.java:32
```

And in local environment these warning are not shown...

There is some classpath problem similar to https://www.programmersought.com/article/47106442813/

After almost day of struggling with it I found a solution

0. **Use Spoon 9.0.0** or later with [this](https://github.com/INRIA/spoon/pull/3818) fix
1. Create classloader with a parent classloader from Spoon Launcher
2. Directly include each *.jar file into classloader URL classpath (not a directory containing jars but each jar in a single URL passed to classloader)
3. Set this classloader as an InputClassLoader

```java
                URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(
                                                                jarUrls.toArray(new URL[0])
                                                                ,spoonAPI.getClass().getClassLoader()
                                                );
                spoonAPI.getEnvironment().setInputClassLoader(urlClassLoader);
```